# Javadoc Percentages

Tags: javadoc

Is there any way in which you could get the percentage of authors in javadoc?
For example, we have these files:

```
/**
* @author Me
*/
class example1{

}
```

```
/*
* @author You
*/
class example2{

}
```

```
/**
* @author Me
*/
class example3{

}
```

Is there any property/method... with which you could something like this?

[Pie chart with percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0E49.png)